# How to depenency injection/register open generic types

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector, generic-collections

I have a microservices architecture using simple injector in each service. The services communicates through Azure Service Bus. I'm currently trying to find a way to implement a generic solution/library for interacting with Azure Service Bus. The library is the core infrastructure of the services and has a topic publisher (for pushing events /messages to azure) and a subscriber (for listening to messages from azure).
Besides that I have a common interface for the events /messages containing an ID and time stamp for creation. I also have a generic interface for event handlers `IEventHandler<T> where T : IEvent`. Now my problem is, how do I best keep my composition root separated from the rest of the code while still being able to register a set of handlers for the different types of events in a given service?

Reading the docs for simple injector suggests a factory or something like that, but my interface is generic and the factory is not which makes public IEventHandler GetHandler (Type eventType) illegal...

**UPDATE**: Added code

Publishing:

```
   public interface IEventPublisher
    {
        Task PublishAsync(IEvent @event);
    }

    public class EventPublisher : IEventPublisher
    {
        private readonly ITopicClient topicClient;

        public EventPublisher(ITopicClient topicClient)
        {
            this.topicClient = topicClient;
        }

        public async Task PublishAsync(IEvent @event)
        {
            try
            {
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(@event);
                var message = new Message()
                {
                    Body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json),
                    PartitionKey = nameof(@event),
                    MessageId = @event.Id.ToString()
                };
                message.UserProperties.Add("Type", @event.GetType().FullName);
                await topicClient.SendAsync(message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Handle error
            }
        }
    }
```

Handling events:

```
public interface IEventHandler<T> where T : IEvent
{
    void HandleEvent(T @event);
}

public interface IEventSubscriber
{
//Currently empty, might need some method for registration of handlers?
}

public class EventSubscriber : IEventSubscriber
{
    private readonly ISubscriptionClient subscriptionClient;

    public EventSubscriber(ISubscriptionClient subscriptionClient, )
    {
        this.subscriptionClient = subscriptionClient;

        var messageHandlerOptions = new MessageHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandler)
        {
            AutoComplete = false
        };

        this.subscriptionClient.RegisterMessageHandler(ProcessMessagesAsync, messageHandlerOptions);
    }

    private Task ExceptionReceivedHandler(ExceptionReceivedEventArgs exceptionReceivedEventArgs)
    {
        var context = exceptionReceivedEventArgs.ExceptionReceivedContext;
        logger.Error($"Message handler encountered an exception {exceptionReceivedEventArgs.Exception}.");
        logger.Error("Exception context for troubleshooting:");
        logger.Error($"- Endpoint: {context.Endpoint}");
        logger.Error($"- Entity Path: {context.EntityPath}");
        logger.Error($"- Executing Action: {context.Action}");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task ProcessMessagesAsync(Message message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BankDataChangedEvent>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body));
        // HERE I NEED SOME CODE TO FETCH/FIND THE RIGHT HANDLER FOR THE EVENT TYPE
        await subscriptionClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
    }
}
```

Most of the pulisher and subscriber are boilerplate code from Microsoft docs for Azure Service Bus with .Net - only slightly modified.

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: I find your question confusing. I don't understand what it is you want to know. So I agree with @Enigmativity: add the code that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Please don't delete comments if it makes understanding the conversation difficult.

Comment: I won't delete comments, why would I? :) I will add some code later when I'm on my laptop again. I was asking this while on the subway

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I know what do you want.
Do you have something like this?

```
internal sealed class CommonEventConsumer :
    IConsumer<Event1>,
    IConsumer<Event2>
{
    private readonly ISomeService _someService;

    public CommonEventConsumer(ISomeService someService)
    {
        _someService = someService;
    }

    public async Task HandleEventAsync(Event1 eventMessage)
    {
        await _someService.DoSomeThing1(eventMessage);
    }

    public async Task HandleEventAsync(Event2 eventMessage)
    {
        await _someService.DoSomeThing2(eventMessage);
    }
}
```

where `IConsumer<Tevent>` is global interface which has method `HandleEventAsync(Tevent event message);` and `CommonEventConsumer` is average consumer in any of your microservice.

Also the publisher is like:

```
public sealed class EventPublisher : IEventPublisher
{
    public async Task PublishAsync<T>(T eventMessage)
    {
        var subscriptions = DependencyResolver.ResolveAll<IConsumer<T>>();

        foreach (var subscription in subscriptions)
        {
            await subscription.HandleEventAsync(eventMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

where I resolve all event subscribers and push messages to them.

If yes, then I have the same structure in my application, and my SimpleInjector registration for eventConsumers look's like that:

```
private static void RegisterConsumers(Container container)
    {
        container.Register<IEventPublisher, EventPublisher>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

        container.Collection.Register(typeof(IConsumer<>), new[] {
            typeof(CommonConsumer),
            typeof(MeasurementEventConsumer),
            typeof(PartRepairEventConsumer),
            typeof(OrderItemEventConsumer),
            typeof(OrderTaskEventConsumer),
            typeof(OrderItemWorkStatusEventConsumer),
            typeof(OrderItemTaskEventConsumer),
            typeof(OrderTaxEventConsumer)

       });
    }
```

Comment: Following guidelines from Steven on simple-injector I would like to keep the container out of my publisher (or generic subscriber - see code above). Also Azure Service Bus is an API that actually sends the message through a service bus which means that my services do not know each other (so looping through subscribers will not do the trick) :)